# Event Registration Confirmation Email missing Custom Location Type Field Data

Tags: civievent, email, registration, confirmation

**Environment**
CiviCRM 5.9.1 with Drupal 7. Have enabled the following permissions for all drupal users: access all custom data, profile create, register for events, view event info, view event participants. We have a custom "Location Type" called "EditedInfo" and a custom profile called "Registration Information" -- the EditedInfo Location Type is set as the default, if it makes a difference. The profile has the default "Your Registration Information" First and Last name fields (Individual - Primary), and the rest of the fields (Email, Phone, Address, etc.,) are of Type "Contact - EditedInfo".

**Problem**
When a user/contact registers for an event everything works flawlessly -- the values for the "EditedInfo" are copied correctly to their fields on the Contact record, the registration occurs and a confirmation email is sent. However, the email has blanks where the values for all the "EditedInfo" information should be. The labels are there, so the template is recognizing the fields, but the values are empty.

**Troubleshooting**
I assumed it was a permissions issue, but I could not get it solved by toggling various permissions on/off. I am not sure what else to look for at this point. I have also switched these "EditedInfo" fields to regular "Primary" fields, and they are successfully included in the email. However, this is undesirable from the CiviCRM administrators perspective and they'd like to use the "EditedInfo" Location Type fields.